# Rails 4: Model logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, rails-activerecord

A quick question:

I've got a FavoriteItem Model which includes `:id :user_id :item_id`

How can I check within a loop through all Items

```
- @items.each do |item|
```

... if the `current_user` has favorited an item?

=> For Example:

```
current_user.id == 243
item.id == 53
```

This db entry exists in FavoriteItems:

```
:id => 1, :user_id => 243, :item_id => 53
```

How can I check in my loop if this item got favorited by the current user?

I am grateful for all your help! Tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a single database call:

```
item.favorited_items.where(:user_id => current_user).exists?
```

You could also wrap that up in a method on `Item`:

```
def favorited_by?(user)
  favorited_items.where(:user_id => user).exists?
end
```

and then say `item.favorited_by?(current_user)` in your loop.

If you're looping over a large number of `items` then you could precompute the current user's favorites to avoid n+1 queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `map` and `include?`

```
@items.each do |item|
  if item.favorited_items.map(&:user_id).include?(current_user.id)
    # yep, there's a match - do something
  end
end
```

If you're going to be using this functionality a lot, you probably want to create a scope on the items model.